# How to Uninstall Nuxt modules and packages

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, node-modules

I'm on Nuxt 2.13 and I wanna remove some packages. previously I would just remove them from the package.json file and would use `npm i` and the package would be removed but now I get this error:

```
Module @nuxtjs/google-gtag not found. Please ensure @nuxtjs/google-gtag is in dependencies and installed.


 FATAL  Cannot find module '@nuxtjs/google-gtag'                                                              17:56:41
Require stack:
- C:\CODES\node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js
- C:\CODES\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js
- C:\CODES\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli.js
- C:\CODES\node_modules\nuxt\bin\nuxt.js

  Error: Cannot find module '@nuxtjs/google-gtag'
  Require stack:
  - node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js
  - node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js
  - node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli.js
  - node_modules\nuxt\bin\nuxt.js
  at Resolver.requireModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:603:31)
  at ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:174:38)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\utils\dist\utils.js:1818:43
  at async ModuleContainer.ready (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:49:5)
  at async Nuxt._init (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:693:5)


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                   │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                              │
   │                                                                   │
   │   Error: Cannot find module '@nuxtjs/google-gtag'                 │
   │   Require stack:                                                  │
   │   - C:\CODES\node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js                 │
   │   - C:\CODES\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js             │
   │   - C:\CODES\node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli.js                   │
   │   - C:\CODES\node_modules\nuxt\bin\nuxt.js                        │
   │                                                                   │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-15T14_26_41_931Z-debug.log
```

I tried `npm uninstall -S -D @nuxtjs/google-gtag` and it worked but then when I uninstalled `express` i got this error again!

how can I safely remove packages from my nuxt app??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your approach is correct, but make sure that the module is not used anywhere.
in the case of Nuxt, besides the package.json, also check the nuxt.config.js (**modules** && **buildModules**) and also the **plugins folder**

docs:

- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#modules
- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules/
- https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/

Comment: yeah , silly me ! forgot about `nuxt.config` . tanx

Comment: no problem , glad you solve the problem